# Copy file to remote dv server shell script

Tags: shell, file-io

But how can I copy a file from one dv server to another with a shell script? It's a small file, and I'd like to use the easiest method, so long as it's secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if your using Linux / UNIX / OS X SSH scp Client

rsync -avz -e ssh user@server1:/var/www/html /var/www/html/

or this

scp -r user@server1:/var/www/html/ /var/www/html/

Comment: Where should I enter the user password for either server?  Also, is one method faster/better than the other?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: if it is the first time you want to copy the file, use scp command and if not use rsync command because it will only update the files that are updated.

Hit enter / command to input the password :)

Comment: you could use ssh public key based authentication. Please refer it here.


http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html